# How to check if the user already rated through template or view function django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

So In my list_detail.html I have included the create_starr.html file where my star rating form is placed.

Now I can Rate a post with a user only once (which I want). But if a user already rated then it goes to the else condition (goes to the create_starr.html file)

But the thing I wanna do is if a user already rated. in post_detail.html I want it to show for example if a user rated 5, I want to show 5 stars in the place of postable star rating form(non editable) in list_detail.html page. But dont know how can I approach that. NOOB HERE.

in my models

```
class List(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField('Genre')
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True)
    posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = RichTextField(null=True,default=' ')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="Movie")
    spoiler_choices = [(False, 'No'),(True, 'Yes')]
    spoiler = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True, choices = spoiler_choices)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length= 300,null=True, blank = True, unique=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}|{self.creator}'
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title + str(self.posted))
        super(List,self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Starr(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,models.CASCADE)
    list = models.ForeignKey(List,models.CASCADE)
    rate = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["user", "list"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + " | " + self.list.title + " | " + str(self.rate)
```

in my views

```
class TheirDetailView(DetailView):
    model = List
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        modell = Review.objects.all()
        starr = Starr.objects.all()
        context["starr"] = starr
        context["modam"] = modell
        return context

def create_starr(request):
    context = {}
    form = StarrForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
    else:
        context['form'] = form
        return render(request, "app/create_starr.html", context)
```

in my create_starr.html

```
<div class="starr_cont">
<form class = "starr" method="POST" action="{% url 'app:create_starr' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>
        <select name="user" required="" id="id_user">
            <option value="{{user.pk}}" selected="">{{user.username}}</option>
          </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <select name="list" required="" id="id_List">
            <option value="{{list.pk}}" selected="">{{list.title}}</option>
          </select>
    </p>
    <div class="comment-stars">
        <span class="stars-post-comments">
            <span class="fa fa-star" id="st1"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star" id="st2"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star" id="st3"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star" id="st4"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star" id="st5"></span>
            </span>
    </div>
    <p>
    <input type="number" name="rate" value="0" required="" id="id_rate" placeholder="Rating">
    </p>
<div><button type="submit">Rate</button></div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For times that users already logged in you can save rating status in database, and if anonymous users can rate you can use [Cookies](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_cookies_handling.htm) or [Sessions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_sessions.htm) how ever both of these can't warranty for preventing users to rate multiple times